# add a range to a published CSV link

Tags: csv, google-sheets, download, date-range

so i remember doing this a while back but i cant seem to remember the syntax:

here is an example of a link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qrtaGu5dwljVbHJeR4RIMWtdZKOauJfJ6nODlPwMRno/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv

i had added a range A1:C5 for example, and was able to download just the range...
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qrtaGu5dwljVbHJeR4RIMWtdZKOauJfJ6nODlPwMRno/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv/RANGEA1:C5

does anyone know the correct syntax of how to add this range to the published url link?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

You will have to append an additional query string parameter to the URL of your published Spreadsheet.

For example your published Spreadsheet in `.csv` has the following URL:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/published-sheet-id/pub?git=worksheet-id&output=csv
```

Now you will download the whole worksheet in a `.csv` file.

You will have to add the `range` query parameter to your URL like this:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/published-sheet-id/pub?git=worksheet-id&range=A1:C4&output=csv
```

Now you get only the desired range downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

i believe the solution was to add &range=A1:C4 after the csv part of the link

https ://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qrtaGu5dwljVbHJeR4RIMWtdZKOauJfJ6nODlPwMRno/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&range=A1:C4